# How to install nodejs in dockerfile using FOSS

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image for my repo using ubuntu.

here is what i have so far:

```
FROM harbor.global.lmco.com/lmc.eo.swf.efoss/ubuntu-22.04:v1.11.3
FROM node:8.2
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# WORKDIR /

ARG EFOSS_USER
ARG EFOSS_TOKEN
ARG http_proxy=http://proxy-zsgov.global.lmco.com:80
ARG https_proxy=http://proxy-zsgov.global.lmco.com:80
ARG no_proxy=".lmco.com,.us.lmco.com,.lmms.lmco.com,.ssc.lmco.com,.gitlab.us.lmco.com,.pages.gitlab.us.lmco.com,.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com"
ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-zsgov.global.lmco.com:80
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy-zsgov.global.lmco.com:80
ARG NO_PROXY=".lmco.com,.us.lmco.com,.lmms.lmco.com,.ssc.lmco.com,.gitlab.us.lmco.com,.pages.gitlab.us.lmco.com,.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com"

ARG REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ARG CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ARG SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

RUN efoss apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends
```

However when I run the script, I get

```
Step 15/15 : RUN efoss apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends
 ---> Running in 3d8deda25bd4
/bin/sh: 1: efoss: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c efoss apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends' returned a non-zero code: 127
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I have tried other commands such as

RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN apt-get install node.js

but none seem to work.

eFoss: It implements a searchable, centralized repository of FOSS that has been approved for immediate use by all employees, regardless of BA.